# Perl regex not working on variable after it has already matched a previous regex

Tags: regex, perl

Please help me figure out why the following does not work like I expect it to. I should be able to skip all of the array items that don't match and then match on any of the ones that get through. Instead, I have to make a copy of the for loop variable $server and match on it after it has been matched by one regex and let through.The variable $server still contains the same string and I would expect to be able to match it to a second regex:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

@servers = ('server01', 'server02', 'vm13', 'vm02');

for my $server ( @servers) {

if ($server !~ m/server01|vm13|vm02/ig ) {

    next;

} else {
    say $server;  # It will print string that contains 
                  # server01, vm13, or vm02

    if ($server =~ m/server01/ig) {

        say $server # It will not print string that 
                    # contains server01 here
    }

    say $server, " again..."; # The variable still works here
}
```

This way does work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

@servers = ('server01', 'server02', 'vm13', 'vm02');

for my $server (@servers) {

my $server_copy = $server;

if ($server !~ m/server01|vm13|vm02/ig ) {

    next;

} else {

    say $server;  # It will print the name of the server 
                    # that contains server01, vm13, or vm02

    if ($server_copy =~ m/server01/ig) {
        say $server # It now prints the name of that server
    }

    say $server, " again..."; # The variable still works here
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for a complete question. I am not sure I fully understand the description -- In your example, do you expect to only see `server02`? Or to _not_ see that one?

Comment: @zdim Thanks for the quick response. I expect it to let servers through that match server01, vm13, vm02. Skipping the ones that don't match those. That is the first use of a regex on the $server variable. Then if the a match is made on server01, it should print the name of that server. That is the second use of a regex on the $server variable. It only works if I create a copy of the $server variable: $server_copy.

Comment: The code you have shown will not compile. Please always `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in your ***real code***, and don't just add them when you post your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, it's the global modifier `/g` in the regex used in scalar context that causes this behavior.

From [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl), under *Global matching*

> In scalar context, successive invocations against a string will have //g jump from match to match, keeping track of position in the string as it goes along

As it remembers its last position it only tries to match *from there* down the string the next time, as explained in answer by [choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba).  A very useful tool in this regard is [use re qw(debug)](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#%27debug%27-mode), with which you'll see in detail what a regex is doing.

I've changed the code a little bit as well.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use diagnostics;

my @servers = ('server01', 'server02', 'vm13', 'vm02');

foreach my $server (@servers) {

    next if not $server =~ m/server01|vm13|vm02/i;

    say $server;  # Prints string with either server01, vm13, or vm02

    if ($server =~ m/server01/i) {
        say "Looking for: $server";
    }   

    say "$server, again..."; # The variable still works here
}
```

---

If the list of servers to keep is long you can make use of `none` from the core [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) module<sup>†</sup>.

```
use List::Util qw(none);

if (none { /$server/ } @keep_servers) {
    say "Skipping $server";
    next;
}
```

There are other ways to manipulate arrays (originally I used `not any`, thanks to [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) for a note).

If you *only* need to skip them then of course you can simply loop over `@keep_servers` instead. Such a list can be constructed as, for example

```
my @keep_servers = grep { not /server02/ } @servers;
```

This may be suitable if you know which to drop and they form a much shorter list than those to keep.

---

<sup>†</sup>  This module is in core [as of Perl 5.20](http://leonerds-code.blogspot.com/2014/06/listutil-additions-in-perl-520.html).

With a version prior to Perl 5.20 the functions `all`, `any`, `none` and `notall` can be found in [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.415/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) module, while simple implementations were shown in `List::Util` docs.

Comment: excellent response. I updated my script and you were 100% correct. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JeffSims You are most welcome :).  Thank you for the question put together well.

Comment: The first regex has a `)` without a `(`.

Comment: @JeffSims I added a bit, unrelated to the direct question, hoping that you may find it useful.

Comment: [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#any) even implements `any` directly.

Comment: @melpomene  Apparently I fell victim to the v5.10 docs I was reduced to at work.  (Looked for it in `List::Util` first!)  Thank you very much, correcting.

Comment: An excellent answer. Note that `List::Util` also has `none`, so `if ( none { /$server/ } @keep_servers ) { ... }` works nicely. But I realise that there are people who are allergic to `unless`, and `none` may cause the same problem!

Comment: @Borodin  Thank you very much for your kind words. Options seem to multiply fast when a more general topic is discussed, like array manipulations. I guess I subconsciously translated 'if not match-any-of' from the original regex, what is interesting.

Comment: @Borodin I have to also say -- I am puzzled by what in this answer deserves a -1, which it got after my last edit. I am also very puzzled by how the question itself deserves a -1. It is an excellent very first question in my opinion. (While a clearly wrong answer doesn't earn that.)

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the `/g` flag. It remembers the position where it matched last time, and tries to match from that position onwards the next time. You can verify it with the string `server01_server01` - it will be printed because it matches the regex twice.

Remove the `/g` flag if you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
if ($server_copy =~ m/server01/ig)
```

to this

```
if ($server_copy =~ m/server01/i)
```